# Is it possible to cancel a message while it's being sent?

Tags: erlang

Process `A` sends a request to `B` after 1 minute with `send_after` (let's call it `request`). But `B` has 1 minute to cancel it.

Can `B` send `cancel` to `A` and prevent that message being sent within this timespan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

When you are using [`erlang:send_after`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send_after-4) it returns a `TimerRef`.
If you want to cancel the request you just need to call `erlang:cancel_timer(TimerRef)` or `erlang:cancel_timer(TimerRef, Options)`.

In your case, if you want process `B` to cancel the message you will have to send `TimerRef` from `A` to `B` and then call `erlang:cancel_timer(TimerRef)` in process `B` in order to cancel this specific send request.

Please take a look at erlang documentation [`erlang:cancel_timer/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#cancel_timer-2) for more information.

Comment: Gonna try that approach, just give me a couple of minutes and I will upvote you :)